# Is there any way to cancel asynchronous functions automatically after a specified time?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying to use discord.py to create a Discord bot. One issue I have run into is that I want an asynchronous function to be run, but after a specified amount of time (e.g. 5 seconds) if it hasn't already returned the rest of the code should resume and the function should be cancelled (so it doesn't continue to run after that). Unfortunately, while I can get the rest of the code to run, the function keeps on running afterwards.

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def testfunc():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Still running.")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Connected!")
    await asyncio.wait([testfunc()],timeout=5,return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print("5 seconds up")

client.run('MY BOT ID')
```

What I intend is that, 5 seconds after printing "Connected!", it prints "5 seconds up" (resuming the rest of the code) and then does not print "Still running." after 10 seconds. When I actually try this, however, both messages get printed.

How do I set it up so that testfunc stops running after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If you only need to run one coroutine,</s> use [wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) instead.

```
await asyncio.wait_for(testfunc(), timeout=5)
```

Note that this will throw an `asyncio.TimeoutError` that you will need to catch

Looking at the docs for [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) it states:

> Unlike wait_for(), wait() does not cancel the futures when a timeout occurs.