# Using `async for` inside a timeout function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, stream, python-asyncio, rtl-sdr

I am trying to print output from an information stream and cancel the stream after 5 seconds. My issue is that [the documentation](https://github.com/pyrtlsdr/pyrtlsdr#:%7E:text=report%20any%20bugs!-,rtlsdraio,-Note%20that%20the) suggests using `async for` to print the data stream, but I am unable to cancel the stream and exit the `main` function after the specified time. I can get the rest of the code to run, but after 5 seconds the function keeps on running. Here is a minimum reproducible example based on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055631/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-asynchronous-functions-automatically-after-a-specifie):

```
import asyncio
import datetime
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr

sdr = RtlSdr()

async def main():
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now() 
    stoptime = starttime + datetime.timedelta(0,5)
    async for sample in sdr.stream():
        if datetime.datetime.now() > stoptime:
            raise StopAsyncIteration 
        else:
            print(sample)       
    return

def printme():
    print("here now")

asyncio.run(main())
printme()
```

Currently, the output ends like this:

```
[-0.05882353+0.12941176j -0.01960784-0.03529412j -0.15294118-0.1372549j
 ... -0.09803922+0.04313725j  0.06666667+0.02745098j
  0.02745098-0.04313725j]
[ 0.01960784+0.0745098j   0.08235294-0.12941176j  0.14509804-0.23137255j
 ...  0.11372549-0.03529412j  0.03529412+0.02745098j
 -0.02745098-0.15294118j]
```

and just sits there.

I understand this is not a minimum working sample since it cannot be copied and run by everyone, but that's also because I'm having trouble substituting something simple for the data stream. I hope I'm still getting the point across. I've tried using await `asyncio.wait_for`, but I haven't figured that out, either. I'm not familiar with `async` operations.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!